# Separate string of HTML elements into strings

Tags: javascript, html, json

What is the best practice to separate a string of multiple HTML elements? I am experimenting with the JSON dump of an article, all the body is bunched together like this:

```
 "<p>"This is a p."</p>[IMAGE]<h1>"this is more text."</h1><p>"OK"</p>[EMBED]<h2>more tags</h2>"
```

Comment: How would you like to separate it? What would you like the output to be?

Comment: @JackBashford I am using document.createElement and I was going to use the .split method, but it's proving tricky and not to be a good solution...

Answer (score 0):

I've constructed both a function that will return an `Array` and another that would return a `NodeList`.

Perhaps one of these will suffice:

```js
let str = `<p>This is a p.</p>[IMAGE]<h1>this is more text.</h1><p>OK</p>[EMBED]<h2>more tags</h2>`;

// Returns NodeList
htmlStringToNodeList = str => {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = str.trim();
  return div.children;
}
console.log(htmlStringToNodeList(str));

// Returns Array 
htmlStringToArray = str => {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = str.trim();
  return Array.from(div.children);
}
console.log(htmlStringToArray(str));
```

Hope this helps,